# Elasticsearch Slow terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I hava a problem with es query and aggregation. All es record count is about 0.1 billion, before adding a terms aggregation, my query is fast, only cost 75ms and all hit count is 105. But after adding a aggregation, like this one:

```
{
    "query": {
        ...
    },
    "aggs": {
        "index": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "index"
            }
         }
     }
}
```

this query will cost 20 second!
My question is: my query result count is only 105, why the aggregation is so slow?
Thanks for any reply!

Comment: [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-execution-hint) might be a helpful read for you.

Comment: Found from [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/slow-simple-aggregation-related-to-a-not-analyzed-string/66117)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have understood from your question, I think this is what you need:

```
{
    "query": {
        ...
    },
    "aggs": {
        "index": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "index",
                "execution_hint": "map"
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Try this and let me know. Explanation for `execution_hint` and discussion helped to tackle your problem can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-execution-hint) and [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/slow-simple-aggregation-related-to-a-not-analyzed-string/66117/3).